# Ring of Witt vectors over an integral domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $A$ is a commutative ring. The ring of Witt vectors $W(A)$ is defined via $X_0^{p^n}+...+p^nX_n$ (not the general one for arbitrary $n$).

I have read somewhere ring of Witt vectors over an integral domain of prime characteristic is an integral domain. Why this is true? And why do we need the prime characteristic condition?

Comment: What is true for a ring that is of prime characteristic?

Comment: I have read from somewhere: $A$ is of char $p$, $W(A)$ is an integra domain if and only if $A$ is an integral domain. But it seems for any ring it is false

Comment: So you're looking for two things, i) a proof in the case of base characteristic $p$, and ii) a counterexample for the general case?

Comment: If $A$ is a $\mathbb Q$-algebra, then $W\left(A\right)$ is isomorphic to $A \times A \times A \times \cdots$, since the ghost map is a ring isomorphism. If $A$ is a $\mathbb F_p$-algebra, then $W\left(A\right)$ is an integral domain by Corollary 6.4 of [Michiel Hazewinkel, *Witt vectors, part 1*, arXiv:0804.3888v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.3888v1)

Comment: If you are using $p$-typical Witt vectors (the one where powers of $p$ occur all over the place) then when $p$ is invertible in the ring $A$ you can invert the effect of all the Witt polynomials and that makes the Witt vectors $W(A)$ as a ring isomorphic to the product of countably many copies of $A$.  This is why $p$-typical Witt vectors are not interesting for their own sake when $A = \mathbf Q$, for instance.

Comment: @KCd $p$-typical means the Witt vector is constructed by $X_0^{p^n}+...+p^nX_n$?

Comment: Yes, that is why I said “powers of $p$ all over the place.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading comments to an answer:

Let $p$ be a prime, $A$ a (commutative, unital) ring and $W(A)$ its ring of ($p$-typical) Witt vectors. References are [Bou] Bourbaki, *Algebre Commutative* ch. IX §1, and [Haz] [Hazewinkel, *Witt vectors. Part 1*, arXiv:0804.3888v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.3888v1).

In particular let $\Phi_n = \sum_{i=0}^n p^i X_i^{p^{n-i}}$ be the $n$-th Witt polynomial. For clarity, I will use $\times$ for the multiplication in $W(A)$, while multiplication in $A$ is just written with a dot $\cdot$.

**Fact 1**: If $W(A)$ is an integral domain, then so is $A$.

*Proof*: For $a,b \in A$, one has $(a,0,0,....) \times (b,0,0,...) = (a \cdot b, 0,0,...)$ ([Bou] no. 6 Prop. 4; [Haz] 5.21.). It follows that non-trivial zero divisors in $A$ give rise to non-trivial zero-divisors in $W(A)$.

**Fact 2**: If $p\cdot 1_A$ is invertible in $A$, then $W(A) \simeq A^\mathbb N$ (countable direct product) as rings. In particular, $W(A)$ has non-trivial zero-divisors.

*Proof*: (This is actually used to construct all the summation and multiplication polynomials.) See [Bou] no.2 Prop. 2 and no. 4 Theoreme 1, and [Haz] Theorem 5.14.

To construct "explicit" zero-divisors e.g. for $A=\mathbb Q$, take e.g. the obvious pair of zero-divisors $g_1:=(1,0,0,...), g_2=(0,1,0,0,...)$ in $\mathbb Q^\mathbb N$ and "pull them back" i.e. find actual Witt vectors $(x_0,x_1,...), (y_0,y_1,...) \in W(\mathbb Q)$ which have $g_1,g_2$ as ghost components, by setting $x_0=1$ and then recursively solving $$\Phi_{n-1}(x_0^p, ..., x_{n-1}^p) + p^n x_n =0 \qquad \text{for } x_n$$
as well as $y_0=0$,

$$\Phi_{0}(y_0^p) + p^1 y_1 = \color{red}{1} \qquad \text{i.e. } y_1=\frac{1}{p}$$

and then recursively

$$\Phi_{n-1}(y_0^p, ..., y_{n-1}^p) + p^n y_n =0 \qquad \text{for } y_{n \ge 2}.$$

I get $x=(1, -\frac{1}{p}, -p^2+p^{p-1}, ...), y= (0, \frac{1}{p}, -p^{p-1}, ...)$. See how all you need is to be able to invert $p$ in $A$, i.e. this works in any $\mathbb Z[\frac{1}{p}]$-algebra.

**Fact 3**: If $p\cdot 1_A =0_A$ and $A$ is an integral domain, then $W(A)$ is an integral domain.

*Proof*: [Haz] Cor. 6.4, or look into the proof of [Bou] no. 8 Prop. 8 (which is stated for fields, but this part does not need the full assumption). The idea is: Let $x',y' \in W(A)$ be non-zero; then they can be written as $V^m((x_0, x_1, ...))$ and $V^n((y_0,y_1,...))$ for certain $m,n \in \mathbb N_0$ and $x_0 \neq 0 \neq y_0$. Now because of the condition on $A$, one has
$$V^m(w_1) \times V^n(w_2) = V^{m+n}(F^n(w_1) \times F^m(w_2))$$
([Bou], no. 8 Prop. 5; [Haz], last of formulae 6.2) for all $w_1, w_2 \in W(A)$; in particular, the $(m+n)$-th component of $x' \times y'$ is $x_0^{p^n} \cdot y_0^{p^m} \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively:

Note the functoriality of Witt vectors: A ring homomorphism $f:R \rightarrow S$ induces a morphism $W(f): W(R)\rightarrow W(S)$ by the rule $W(f)((r_0, r_1, r_2, \dots ))=(f(r_0), f(r_1), f(r_2), \dots)$. In particular, observe that if $f$ is injective, then so is $W(f)$.

Now a very classical fact about Witt vectors is: If $k$ is a perfect field of characteristic $p>0$, then $W(k)$ is a DVR (This is e.g. somewhere in Serre's *Local Fields* I believe).

So now, if $R$ is a domain of charactestic $p$, we can embed it into its fraction field $k_0$ and in turn embed $k_0$ into its algebraic closure $k$. This way, we get an injective morphism $R \hookrightarrow k$, which induces an injection $W(R)\hookrightarrow W(k)$. In particular, $W(R)$ is a subring of the domain $W(k),$ hence a domain itself.